# How do I add columns to a dataframe with dynamic header names?

Tags: r, shiny

I have a data frame where I want to be able to add as many columns as I want. The catch is that I want the header of each column to be created with a textInput. So far I have:

```
library(shiny)
library(tibble)

ui <- fluidPage(
  textInput("a", "a", "a"),
  numericInput("b", "b", 1),
  actionButton("add", "add"),
  tableOutput("sum"),
  fileInput("file1", "Choose .xlsx File", accept = ".xlsx")
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  dat1<-reactiveVal()
  
  observe({
    file <- input$file1
    ext <- tools::file_ext(file$datapath)
    
    req(file)
    validate(need(ext == "xlsx", "Please upload a csv file"))
    
    cin2<-read_xlsx(file$datapath, sheet=3)
    
    dat1(cin2)
  })
  
  
  observeEvent(input$add, {
    dat1(tibble::add_column(dat1(), input$a=input$b))
  })
  
      output$sum <- renderTable(dat1())

  }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

But this just gives me a complicated error such as:

```
Error in parse(file, keep.source = FALSE, srcfile = src, encoding = enc) : 
  C:/Users/DCOLANTO/OneDrive - Environmental Protection Agency (EPA)/Profile/Desktop/IEX_Shiny-101922/reactivedataframe.R:52:51: unexpected '='
51:   observeEvent(input$add, {
52:     dat1(tibble::add_column(dat1(), names(input$a)=
                                                      ^
```

Could anyone please help me understand where I am going wrong here? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to wrap `input$a` in `!! sym()` and use the walrus operator `:=` to assign:

```r
tibble::add_column(dat1(), !! sym(input$a) := input$b)
```

However, I couldn't test because I don't have your excel file.